# spring boot validation i18n message of placeholder

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Bean

```java
@Length(min = 1, max = 40, message = "{i18n.reg.validator.firstName.length}")
private String firstName;
```

Message

```
i18n.reg.validator.firstName.length = Firstname must be between {1} and {2} characters long.
```

Here is my config for i18n.

```java
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new FixedLocaleResolver(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        return new DbMessageSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
```

When i do valid.

```java
    @PostMapping("/customer/reg")
    @ResponseBody
    void reg(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
//        customerService.add(customer);
    }
```

I get the error message is `Firstname must be between 1 and 2 characters long.`. It doesn't get the value of `min` and `max` from `@Length` to format message. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change {1} and {2} with {min} and {max}

Comment: I tried, then i get error `Input string format: min`

Comment: Here working example https://github.com/potievdev/spring-boot-i18-example

Comment: In my case everything works as expected.  Only one difference - I used as message source file, not database